# Cutscenes Blender Game Engine (BGE)

Tags: game-engine, camera

How do you add a video or film in the blender game engine before a level starts or something?

Answer (score 1):

What you'd basically do is create a scene with a plane and a camera pointed at the plane, and make the plane use your cutscene or video file as its texture. Then, using a Delay logic brick or something similar, you'd switch from that scene to another scene, which contains the game stage or level.

If you want a live animation to play, just animate the camera and the objects in the first scene, and use a Delay sensor again.

This video does a good job of explaining a method of implementing the same method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2W_fQayYcA It's a video by SuperGloop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but one way you might do this is to create a game scene and an intro scene.[image]
Then animate your camera with LocRotScale[image] 
or use a bezier curve[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create your cinematic in a completely different scene, then use 'Load Scene' logic brick to switch back and forth between the actual game and the cut scene.